# Declaration of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wrote a function that checks some numbers with a second function and returns an array.

After checking that the code works, I noticed that I had to declare a new array (arr) in the first function in order to solve it.

```
function calc(a, b) {
  arr = []
  for(a;a<=b;a++) isPow(a) ? arr.push(a) : a
  return arr
}
```

I wanted to try to create an array right in the only place the array is necessary which is where push(a) is. 
I thought about something like this:

```
function calc(a, b) {
  return for(a;a<=b;a++) isPow(a) ? [].push(a) : a
}
```

But obviously it won't work.
Is there any way in JavaScript to do something close to this?

Comment: The argument to `return` has to be an expression, not a statement.

Comment: `[].push(a)` creates a new array every time it's executed, it doesn't push onto the same array each time.

Comment: What's the point of `: a` in the conditional expression? Just write `if (isPow(a)) { arr.push(a); }`

Comment: Even if you could use a `for` statement in `return`, how would it know that the value of that should be the array?

Comment: You're right, there's no point for that : a . I just wanted to practice that short if else statement and forgot to delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using higher-order functions, yes.

```
function calc(a, b) {
  return [...Array(b - a + 1).keys()].map(x => a + x).filter(x => isPow(x));
}
```

Explanation:

- `Array(b - a + 1)` will create an array whose length is the amount of elements between `a` and `b`, inclusive.
- `.keys()` will yield the indices of that array, i.e. the numbers between `0` and `b - a`, inclusive.
- `[...iterator]` will create an array consisting of all the elements of the iterator (i.e. the numbers between `0` and `b - a`, inclusive).
- `.map(x => x + a)` will fix the range, producing the numbers between `a` and `b`, inclusive.
- `.filter(x => isPow(x))` will produce a new array, with only elements that satisfy `isPow`.